# How to proxy pass to another port (multiple)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to proxy pass based on the path to another port (multiple) using NginX.

Example:
/ -> :3000
/test -> :3001

I already config my nginx.conf like this:

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  www.xxx.domain.com;

        gzip off;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.co.id.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.co.id.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers XXX
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.184.0.4:3000;
        }


        location = /test {
                proxy_pass http://10.184.0.4:3001;
        }

       }
```

It's success for the /, but for the /test route it's get redirected to port :3000 to the Not Found Page.

Any suggestion to success the proxy pass?

Comment: Your nginx configuration is correct. please check your application

Comment: but why did it goes to :3000 first, I tried to switch the location order but still failed.

Comment: you change your question from /admin to /test right? so I suggest you to remove `=` before `/test`

Comment: yup, I tried to change the path n remove the `=` or using `^~` but still get directed to 3000